# Copied data from S3 to Neptune instance | Need to view my data with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, amazon-neptune

I have copied data from S3 to AWS Neptune instance (4 CSV files).

As per the AWS document, created RDF4 console to connect to Neptune instance.

In this console as per document created Neptune repository also.

Now I want  see may data, how we can write the query now.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql-rdf4j-console.html

I have opened Neptune repository in my RDF4J console now.

How  to execute the SPARQL queries to check my data?

Comment: Documentation looks definitive. Say `sparql select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 100`.

Comment: See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format.html

Comment: in RDF4J, you don't need the keyword "sparql" before the query. "could not be parsed" isn't helpful. and which query?

Comment: *"I am trying to execute PREFIX"* - ehm, what?

Comment: @Srinivas Is there anything else you would like help with with regards to this question?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is supported only for property graph (Gremlin) data [1]. Neptune does not let you insert Gremlin data and query over SPARQL, if that's what you're trying to do.

Once you bul load data using one of the supported SPARQL dta formats listed above, you can try querying in various ways (CURL requests, HTTP requests programmatically using something libraries like rdf4j, Use GUI tools like RDF4J workbench etc.).

The easiest way to try basic requests would be using CURL, as follows:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary 'query=select ?s ?p ?o where {?s ?p ?o} limit 10' http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/sparql
curl -X POST --data-binary 'update=INSERT DATA { <http://test.com/s> <http://test.com/p> <http://test.com/o> . }' http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/sparql
```

More Info:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql-http-rest.html

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql-java.html

[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-sparql-rdf4j-workbench.html